# Switching between implementations in C precompiler

Tags: c, precompile

I'm fairly new to programming in C. My problem is that I have two implementations of a function and I want to be able to switch between them easily.

Right now I define the two implementations of the function as function_implementation1 and function_implementation1 in the files "funtion_implementation1.h" and "funtion_implementation2.h" respectively. To switch between them I have the following file:

```
#define IMPLEMENTATION1

#ifdef IMPLEMENTATION_1
    #include "funtion_implementation1.h"
    #define myFunction function_implementation1
#endif

#ifdef IMPLEMENTATION_2
    #include "funtion_implementation2.h"
    #define myFunction function_implementation2
#endif
```

In order to switch from one implementation to the other I just have to change the first line. This approach works, and I was satisfied with it for a while, but now it is bugging me that I have to open this file so often. I have a parameters.h file where I define all my parameters and I would rather choose which implementation to use in that file. Sadly, moving the first line to that file does not work. If I do that myFunction is not defined.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't quite see the problem. Just use the same name for the function in both implementations, instead of aliasing via `#define` to a common name, and should be there.

Comment: Why not make one a default, e.g. `#ifndef IMPLEMENTATION2` then use the default include and define. If you compile with `gcc ... -DIMPLEMENTATION2 ...` you get the second version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should include your parameters file where you use alias, macros, etc:

```
#include "Parameters.h"
```

also, all your headers files should start with:

```
#ifndef __FILE_H__
    #define __FILE_H__

// definitions go there

#endif
```

This prevents nested include of header files

Comment: Thanks a lot, including "Parameters.h" did the trick. Silly of me not to think about that. I already had the include guards.

Answer (score 1):

Use [preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html), specifically the `-D` option. If you wanted to use `IMPLEMENTATION1`, when you are compiling that file on the command line (or in IDE), add `-D IMPLEMENTATION1`. This defines that macro. Same works for any macro

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't think that's very convenient either. Im using Microsoft Visual Studio and changin the compile options is a lot of work :)